# Selecting element within shadow dom

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm building web component and it's all going fine, but I have this problem when I try to get width of element and it logs me

> Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null

and line bellow that it logs actual width.

My code:

```
attributeChangedCallback(name, oldVal, newVal) {
    const innerBar = this.shadow.querySelector('.progress-name-inner');
    const progressTitle = this.shadow.querySelector('.progress-title');
    console.log(progressTitle.getBoundingClientRect().width)

    switch (name) {
        case 'title':
            this._title = newVal || '';
            break;

        case 'complete':
            this._complete = parseInt(newVal) || 0;

            innerBar.style.width = this.complete + '%'
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the problem is '.progress-title' doesn't exist when the execution of the code occurs, so **progressTitle** turns to be null. You need to fix that.

Comment: Yea, i figured that, but what is the reason for that.. Why it doesn't throw error on innerBar.style.width. I'm also working with element within shadow..

Answer (score 1):

When an HTML element attribute is defined inline (in the HTML code), the `attributeChangedCallback()` method is called before the `connectedCallback()` method.

So you'd better set the Shadow DOM HTML content in the `constructor()` method if you want to process Custom Elements attributes.

Also, when an exception is thrown the method excution stops, that's why the error on `innerBar.style.width` is not thrown.